# how can we get Throughput in jtl file generated via running script in non gui mode?

Tags: jmeter

In JTL file : we get Average response time and Average Bytes along with response code and resp.onse message . How can we get throughput via running script in non gui mode

Answer (score 0):

Once Test execution is completed, you can load the `.jtl/.csv` results file into one of listeners which gives average values like `Aggregate Report`, `Aggregate Graph` or `Summary report`. These listeners calculate the averages of different KPIs.

**All JMeter listeners can be used post the test with the results file to plot the grpahs or to calculate the average values**. (not only in GUI mode, during the test)

Comment: without using J meter Gui how can we calculate throughput suing Average bytes and Average time , number of users from JTL file.For example :Average time 1688ms , Standard deviation= 96.44 ,Average bytes =41763.3bytes , number of users =3

Comment: As far as I know, you need to write custom scripts for that. Or insert the .jtl file entries to DB (like SQLite or similar, each row is a record) and run the query.

Comment: yes, but my calculations for KB/ sec and throughput are getting matched  for single user .Using average bytes and response time given in jtl file. But when same script is run for more than one users then KB/sec is different .

Comment: It would be for many reasons. throughput vary based on the user load. so, once users increased, throughput also increases. I am not sure using average bytes and response time will yield correct throughput for multiple users (though the formula seems correct for single user)